# Service worker - chrome mobile, works only in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I am trying to use service worker to make my website work offline. 
My sw.js:

```
var cacheName = 'v40aswedsdfsadg';
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1LEGGLbrp3hqsN_CyZQMpmrUs5QTajjgjXyCgfwwIDQk/1/public/values?alt=json";
var cacheFiles = [
    './',
    './index.html',
    './js/app.js',
    './css/app.css',
    './vendor/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './vendor/angular/angular.min.js',
    './vendor/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js',
    './vendor/gs2json.js',
    url
];

self.addEventListener('install',function(e){
    console.log('[SW] install');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache){
            console.log('[SW] add cache');
            return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener('activate',function(e){
    console.log('[SW] activate');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames){
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName){
                    if(thisCacheName!==cacheName){
                        console.log('[SW] delete cache: '+thisCacheName+'->'+cacheName);
                        return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                    }
                }));
        })
    );
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('[SW] fetch: '+event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(function(response) {
                // Cache hit - return response
                if (response) {
                    console.log('[SW] Loaded "'+response.url+'" from cache');
                    return response;
                }
                var fetchRequest = event.request.clone();

                return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                    function(response) {
                        console.log('[SW] fetch: '+response.url);

                        if(!response || response.status !== 200) {
                            console.log('[SW] fetch failed: ',!response, response.status!==200);
                            alert('fail');
                            return response;
                        }

                        var responseToCache = response.clone();

                        caches.open(cacheName)
                            .then(function(cache) {
                                console.log('[SW] put response to cache');
                                cache.put(event.request, responseToCache);
                            });
                        return response;
                    }
                );
            })
    );
});
```

It works great when using chrome.

It doesn't work on chrome mobile:
 - I don't get offline error (it means service worker works)
 - data from https won't load
 - first load works fine (when fetching data from url)
 - second and any next load doesn't work (blank page = no data loaded)

It works on mobile chrome when in incognito mode (data fetched from cache fine).

Anyone who can help me figure this out?

Edit:
Just tested it on mobile firefox and it does work too. It seems it is a problem with mobile chrome..

Comment: I used local storage to keep https responses. Other files are kept by service worker. Everything works now fine. Quess its mobile chrome bug to fix.